# Can we use lower case letters for vendor name

Tags: magento2, vendor

Facing an issue with the vendor name.

{"0":"Param resource doesn't pass validation: 'test_SimpleModule::test' does not match against pattern '/^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]+_[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]+::[A-Za-z_0-9]+$/'","1":"#0

In the Magento marketplace, the vendor name is in lowercase, when I've updated my module vendor name to the lowercase I am getting the above error.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This portion of the regex `/^[A-Z]` means:

> Begins with upper-case character in range A-Z

So yes the namespace must begin with a capital letter.